# ASP Core Static Files Taking a Long Time to Refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, static-pages

I'm building an Angular 2 / ASP Core WebApi project.  I have it running in VS Code.  I have "`tsc -p wwwroot -w`" running in a console and when I update a `.ts` file and refresh my browser I see the change immediately.

But when I make a change to a `.html` file, it takes minutes for the change to be reflected in the browser.   Does ASP Core static pages cache files that is has served?  Is there a way to turn that off??

Comment: Did you disable your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, to be extra sure I even did "Shift-F5" and then I did "Ctrl-F5" to Chrome.